# Cant get the value from the form_droplist

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get the value selected on form_droplist, but the value all get its "name" and dont pass me the value from the droplist, can someone give me a hint so i can proceed?

VIEW:

```
<form method="POST" action="tableQuery">
   <label> Select your Table: </label><br />
   <?php echo form_dropdown('table',$tables) ?>
   <br /> <br /> 
   <label> Number of Restrictions: </label>
   <input type="text" name="numRow" /> <br /><br />
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Build Restrictions</button>
</form>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 public function tableQuery()
 {
  $tblName = $this->input->post('table');
  $numRows = $this->input->post('numRow');
 }
```

Comment: what is inside $tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you're not passing any value to dropdown, u can see the options, but are just passing the name to every option instead of passing the value to. u could the other way too

```
<select name='table'>
       <option value = "0">Select...</option>
       <?php for($counter=0; $counter < count($tables); $counter++): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $tables[$counter]['name']; ?>"> <?php echo $tables[$counter]['name']; ?></option>
       <?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

its more than 1 line but easy to track bugs. Good Luck